# Linq filtering entity's collection ends up in LINQ to Entities casting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

ASPNET MVC5 web app

In getting Products, whose relation with other entities is described by following models, I need to filter only those Products.Category.CategoryTrans  whose language_id equals the culture param.

Please note I need to pass the result as an IQueryable to subsequent paging and sorting methods, already implemented.

Models:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual CategoryTrans CategoryTrans { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryTrans> CategoryTrans { get; set; }
}

 public class ISO_Languages
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string name_en { get; set; }
    public string name_fr { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public string name_de { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
}

 public class CategoryTrans
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("category_id")]
    public virtual Category categoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("language_id")]
    public virtual ISO_Languages languageId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Following query returns ALL CategoryTrans in p.Category.CategoryTrans, that means any category translation

```
public static IQueryable<Product> ActiveProductsPerUser(BaseContext db, string userid, string culture)
    {

        var query = (from p in db.Products
                     join ct in db.CategoryTrans
                     on p.CategoryID equals ct.category_id
                     join l in db.ISO_Languages
                     on ct.language_id equals l.ID
                     where l.code.Substring(0, 2) == culture
                     select p);

        return query;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is filtering, for every product, the single category translation, depending on culture input parameter.
Something like:

```
public static IQueryable<Product> ActiveProductsPerUser(BaseContext db, string userid, string culture)
    {
        var query = from p in db.Products
                     join ct in db.CategoryTrans
                     on p.CategoryID equals ct.category_id
                     join l in db.ISO_Languages
                     on ct.language_id equals l.ID
                     where l.code.Substring(0, 2) == culture
                     select new Product
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Description = p.Description,
                        CategoryTrans = p.Category.CategoryTrans.Where(b => b.language_id.Equals(l.ID)).SingleOrDefault()
                    };
        return query;
    }
```

but getting error:

> The entity or complex type 'xyz.DAL.Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Looking for this specific error I now tried projecting onto a DTO:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryTrans CategoryTrans { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<Product> ActiveProductsPerUser(BaseContext db, string userid, string culture)
    {
        var query = from p in db.Products
                     join ct in db.CategoryTrans
                     on p.CategoryID equals ct.category_id
                     join l in db.ISO_Languages
                     on ct.language_id equals l.ID
                     where l.code.Substring(0, 2) == culture
                     select new ProductDTO
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Description = p.Description,
                        CategoryTrans = p.Category.CategoryTrans.Where(b => b.language_id.Equals(l.ID)).FirstOrDefault()
                    };
        return query.Cast<Product>();
    }
```

And that is now working as expected, returning only required translation to CategoryTrans.
So the query works now BUT casting ProductDTO to needed Product returns:

> Unable to cast the type 'xyz.Controllers.ProductDTO' to type 'xyz.Models.Product'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I cannot find a solution to this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an answer to the

> The entity or complex type 'xyz.DAL.Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

error. I eventually solved the problem by adding a

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual string LocalizedCategoryName { get; set; }
```

to Product model Class, in charge for displaying localized category name, and moving the filtering to the ViewModel, setting two nested foreach loops, returning a new List of fully localized products:

```
private List<Product> _LocalizedProductList = new List<Product>();

public List<Product> LocalizedProductList
    {
        get
        {
            HttpUtilities HttpHelper = new HttpUtilities();
            string culture = HttpHelper.getFullCulture();
            int IsoCode = GenericUtilities.getIsoID(culture, db);
            List<Product> localized = new List<Product>();

            foreach (Product p in _LocalizedProductList)
            {
                foreach (CategoryTrans c in p.Category.CategoryTrans)
                {
                    if (c.language_id.Equals(IsoCode))
                    {
                        Product x = new Product
                        {
                            ID = p.ID,
                            LocalizedCategoryName = c.name,
                            DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                            DateExpire = p.DateExpire,
                            DateLastModified = p.DateLastModified,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            Description = p.Description,
                            IsApproved = p.IsApproved,
                            IsDeleted = p.IsDeleted,
                            ProductImages = p.ProductImages,
                            User = p.User
                        };
                        localized.Add(x);
                    };
               }
        }
        return localized;
    }

    set { _LocalizedProductList = value; }
}
```

No idea if it's the best or the only way to do it, but works as intended. I can now stay with the simple query and pass the returned IQueryable of Product onto the sorting and paging async method or whatever. Whenever I am done, the result is being assigned to ViewModel.LocalizedProductList, where the getter takes care of the final filtering. Thanks to wonderbell for the suggestion that one possible solution could be to first select the Products, then iterate over them to assign the required property. That's why upvoted his/her post even it cannot be considered as a complete (or even partial) solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are able to cast ProductDTO to Product model, these objects will not be tracked automatically by EF.

One possible solution may be to first select the Products, then iterate over them to assign the required property.

Comment: Thanks, do you think there could be a maybe completely different approach to the problem? I am afraid iterating over Products as suggested could be a time and resource consuming solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your first (failed) query, I believe teh select can be replaced with :

```
 select new Product
 {
     ID = p.ID,
     Name = p.Name,
     Description = p.Description,
     CategoryTrans = ct
 };
```

which may work.

Otherwise, you cannot Cast<> from one object type to another unless they have a base/derived relationship.  Otherwise, you'll need to convert them:

in Product DTO, add:

replace :

```
 return query.Cast<Product>();
```

with:

```
 return  query.Select(p=> new Product 
            {
              ID = p.ID,
              Name = p.Name,
              Description = p.Description,
              CategoryTrans = p.CategoryTrans
              };
```

UPDATE:
Ok, let's try something different.  **Drop** the select from the query, and just use the `p` object:

```
public static IQueryable<Product> ActiveProductsPerUser(BaseContext db,
                                                        string userid, string culture)
{
    var query = from p in db.Products
                 join ct in db.CategoryTrans
                 on p.CategoryID equals ct.category_id
                 join l in db.ISO_Languages
                 on ct.language_id equals l.ID
                 where l.code.Substring(0, 2) == culture;
    return query;
}
```

that will leave the `CategoryTrans` property null, but it will get you through this and the other manipulations of the query. When you get to the end, and are actually doing things with the result, then pull out the `p.Category.CategoryTrans.Where(b => b.language_id.Equals(l.ID)).FirstOrDefault()` to get the CategoryTrans